# CryptographicException 'The data is invalid' for ProtectedData.Unprotect

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I have an IIS hosted WCF service that uses the `ProtectedData` class in order to encrypt some data. Just simple:

```
ProtectedData.Protect(data, null, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
```

and

```
ProtectedData.Unprotect(encryptedData, null, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
```

It all worked fine on the development machine, but something failed when I deployed the WCF service on a server (Windows Server 2008 R2).

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The data is invalid.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Byte[] encryptedData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
```

The thing is that the protection data works fine. No error, I have the encrypted data, it seems ok. But the program fails to decrypt.
I have double checked everything that could have gone wrong. I even tried a small example in which I decrypted the data imediatelly after encryption (no other operation or conversions involved that can cause other errors). It still fails.
I tried to identify solutions on the Internet. Most of them where regarding the key being invalid and had solutions that didn't apply to my case.

Can someone guide me to find out what went wrong?

Comment: Is the unprotecting happening on the same machine as the protecting? It won't work if it's not.

Comment: @zindorsky: All the operations happen on the same machine.

Comment: Check if the entropy is identical in both cases (you specify null, possibly try an empty array?). Make very sure you don't store anything in a `string` without specifying a correct encoding. This goes for the key as the data and possible additional entropy.

Comment: @owlstead: I have tried with stating an actual entropy, with no success. The strings are stored as they are received, I don't modify the encoding.

Comment: @CoralDoe just to be 100% sure, you don't encode the `Byte[]` to a string and back?

Comment: @owlstead: At first, the `byte[]` was converted into a string, but in order to isolate the problem I modified to program so no other operations occur between `Protect` and `Unprotect`.

Comment: Have you been able to duplicate with `SDataProtectionScope::CurrentUser`?

Comment: Also, check the event log and try to get an error number from the failure. There are some similar failures on [Microsoft Connect](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6c0ab70f-ac8b-4e50-a73d-0f365c36787c/simple-installation-configuration-failing-on-2008-r2-server-with-cryptogrpahyexception?forum=sharepointadminprevious).

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was caused by just an old (not updated) encoded string in the DB. I updated the encoded string in the DB to the new one.

Just create a temporary variable:

```
var keyToProtectAndPutToDB = protector.Protect("MyUnProtectedKey123");
```

And replace the existing value of the `keyToProtectAndPutToDB` in your DB and delete this temp variable.